# is it possible to automate the web & mobile app in the same automation framework?

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, mobile-application, mobile-website

I would like to have a single functional automation framework in java maven for testing the scenario such as Gmail login on the following:

1. Desktop Web Browser
2. Mobile Web Browser &
3. Mobile App

Comment: Have a look at this, https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/getting-started/java

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a custom framework using Maven, Java, Selenium and Appium that would trigger the driver based on the scenario.

You can refer below playlist for code and understanding the implementation.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9ok7C7Yn9A-Hjqo9YlDl2XRVLR-6JPvH